# My code continues to print out zeros and I have no idea why

Tags: c

Does anybody see the error I seem to miss? It just continues to print 0.00 without stopping not sure why its doing. It was working earlier and I didn't make any changes to the while that would affect it so I'm really confused.

`

```
 int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
   {
int i, j, numStudents;
double total, average, difference, lessThan, greater, exchange;

 total = 0;

while (scanf("%1d", &numStudents) != EOF)
{
    /* Ends program at zero */
    if (!numStudents)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    double amountSpent[numStudents];

    total = 0;
    greater = 0;
    lessThan = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
        {
           scanf("%1lf\n", &amountSpent[i]);
            total += amountSpent[i];

        }


        /* cleans total, than calculates */

        average = total/numStudents;



    exchange = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
        {
            difference = amountSpent[i] - average;

            if (difference < 0)
            {
                lessThan += difference;
            }
            else
            {
                greater += difference;
            }

        }

 /*   if (-lessThan > greater)
    {
            exchange = -lessThan;
    }

    else
    {
        exchange = greater;
    }
   */

    exchange = (-lessThan > greater)? -lessThan : greater;
    printf("$%.2f\n", exchange);

}
return 0;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

User input is confused without prompts and use of the `scanf()` trailing `'\n'`.  Else code does work although some ideas may help.

Strange to limit input numeric input to 1 character, - recommend dropping the `1` before the specifier.

Also test against `== 1` rather than `!= EOF` to cope with non-numeric input.

```
// while (scanf("%1d", &numStudents) != EOF)
while (puts("Enter students (0 to quit)", scanf("%d", &numStudents) == 1)
```

Good idea to check results of user input.  Drop the `scanf()` trailing `'\n'`

```
// scanf("%1lf\n", &amountSpent[i]);
puts("Enter amount spent");
if (1 != scanf("%lf", &amountSpent[i])) {
  return 1;
}
```